# Невозможно отправить комментарий WordPress

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

В Wordpress последней версии возникает проблема с отправкой комментария.
Независимо от того, зарегистрирован пользователь или нет, при попытке отправить текст сообщения сайт редиректит на файл wp-comments-post.php. При этом на самой странице отображается текст "Спам не пройдет".

1. Никаких плагинов, связанных с комментариями, капчей, антиспамом и проч. не подключено
2. Используется стандартный модуль комментариев WP
3. Из админки сайта функционал работы с комментариями полностью рабочий (с правами админа можно ответить, удалить, отклонить любой комментарий)
4. На странице поста уже существующие комментарии выводятся нормально, но ответить на них тоже нельзя

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите логи на сервере, может быть это прояснит проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.
У вас бекдор на сайте, ищите по словам "Спам не пройдет".
С уважением Дмитрий Васильевич.

Comment: Вот по теме http://www.wpmayor.com/how-to-create-a-backdoor-to-a-wordpress-website/. А в остальном ищите бекдор.